# TFS Apply Label - label with name alreay exists

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

So I'm trying to apply a label to my source in TFS and I'm getting notification that the label name I'm supplying alreay exists.

Now, I agree, the same name exists in another directory in a different solution. So is the label name global to root of TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label has a concept of **scope**.

> Label names must be unique throughout a specified scope. When you add
>   a label, you reserve the use of that label name at or under the
>   specified or implied scope. The default value for the *@scope*
>   parameter is the team project, for example, `$/TeamProject1`.

So under the same Team Project, the Label name is unique. However, you could use a  [tf label command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/label-command-team-foundation-version-control) to change the scope:

> *`@scope</i></p></td>`*
>
> **Specifies a Team Foundation version control server directory within which the labelname is unique.** This parameter lets you independently
>   create, manage, retrieve, and delete one label or set of labeled items
>   when two labels of the same name are in different parts of the Team
>   Foundation version control server.